# asp.net mvc data annotation with subsonic 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, subsonic3

Has anyone built an application using asp.net mvc with data annotation for validation and subsonic 3.0 for BOL generation?

I am using IDataErrorInfo in partial class at the moment and would like to move to data annotation but i'm not sure how to do it with subsonic 3.0 has my object generator.

I'm using MVC 1.0

I would like to find a code sample to add data annotation to subsonic 3.0 generated object.

Thanks

Comment: incase your still interested i did this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321614/mvc-net-subsonic-auto-generate-metadata-classes-from-tt  it auto mates the generation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution using buddy class

[adding-dataannontations-to-generated-partial-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232497/adding-dataannontations-to-generated-partial-classes/1232781#1232781)